# caffe CNN: Pooling across the channels

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I have a nxmx16x1 conv layer and I would like to do pooling across the channel, so the result has dimension of nxmx1x1.

any suggestions? as far as I know pooling does not have axis param, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `axis` param. Simply use non-uniform kernel/stride:

```
layer {
  name: "pool16x1"
  type: "Pool"
  bottom: "input"
  top: "output"
  pooling_param {
    kernel_size: 16
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 16
    stride: 1
    # ...
   }
}
```

should do the trick...